# How to concatenate two digits with saving integer properties JavaScript

Tags: javascript, char

Hello i want to concatenate two digits or numbers, but with saving properties of integer format, not like char

```
var a = 100 ;
var b = 10 ;
var c = "" + a + b;
return c
```

'10010' - this is (char) 
i need (integer)

Comment: You are missing `+` between `"" c`.

Comment: you really want `c = c + b`?

Comment: you really want c = c + b? – Nina Scholz 2 hours ago 
Thank you i had a mistake. It should be **c= "" + a+b**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your string into number using [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```
var a = 100 ;
var b = 10 ;
var c = parseInt(a + "" + b);
return c
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add the values to a string and use an [unary `+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) for getting a number.

```js
var a = 100,
    b = 10,
    c = +('' + a + b);

console.log(c);
console.log(typeof c);
```